# Some aliases return 'No mapping found'

Tags: macos, bash, alias

After editing .bash_profile, .bashrc, .inputrc
dotfile config my aliases went silly.

Some aliases work as expected.
Others for no apparent reason return:
No mapping found
Press ENTER or type command to continue

[image]
bash GNU bash, version 3.2.57, Yosemite 10.10.3, iterm2

Comment: Did you tried to use the vim full path (`/usr/bin/vim`)?

Comment: @jherran yes I did, with and without. All aliases reside in .bashrc

Comment: If you have problems with aliases please add the definition of the alias to the question, otherwise it will be very difficult to help you. Also, please don't add screenshots of Terminal, copy/paste the relevant text instead and apply code formatting (the {} button).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with aliases but with vim maps.
A satisfactory answer can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214794/no-mapping-found